# How to export and import a database for SQL Server 2017 on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd, datagrip

Linux Mint 18.3 x64
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux

Microsoft documentation [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) the related info for SQL Server installed on Windows, but my SQL Server 2017 instance is installed on Linux. How to export and import a database for SQL Server 2017 on Linux? Is it possible to do through `sqlcmd` or `JetBrains DataGrip` or other way? It is very interesting for me how to do it through the script.

Comment: Define `import` and `export` and why you need it. It's quite likely you don't. For example, SQL Server has real per-database backup and restore so it doesn't need scripting as a workaround. Importing/exporting data makes sense per *table*. SSIS is a full ETL tool, SSMS also has Import/Export wizards. `bcp` also works for bulk import/export.

Comment: For example, I want to copy (or move) my database to other server.

Comment: Backup/restore.  You don't need to export anything. It's an online operation too, which means clients won't even notice you are taking a backup. Or detach, copy the files to the other server, attach. Obviously an offline operation, but you probably wouldn't care eg for dev/testing databases

Comment: Check [Backup and Restore SQL Server databases on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-linux-2017). Backups can also be compressed, saving not only space but crucially, IO during the backup/restore operation.

Comment: Detach/copy/attach is also available through the [Copy Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) wizard in SSMS. The wizard generates a reusable SSIS package that you can save and reuse or modify.

Comment: Thank you. I will learn this info.

Comment: More ways to copy databases [are covered here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-to-other-servers?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: you need to keep in mind *why* you want to perform each task, not how it's done. There are many ways to export/move data but each one is suitable for a different scenario. What is the actual scenario? Disaster recovery? -> Backup/Restore. Availability? -> Always On. Replication has its own services. ETL? -> SSIS .

Comment: I learn sql server through the book about the sql server 2005. It describes some example databases but they are absent in sql server 2017 (pubs, northwind, adventureworks).

Comment: 2005 is far, far, far too old. It doesn't have most of the functionality, features found in 2017, and many of its features are *already* deprecated and removed.

Comment: You'll find a lot of courses through Pluralsight, available for free through the [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/) program. The sample databases can be found in [the SQL Server Samples Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples). Eg the sample database used since ~2014 is [WorldWideImporters](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/wide-world-importers-v1.0)

Comment: Thank you! I will learn these sources.